# setInterval problems with function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, graph-theory

I'm trying to draw visual representation of sorting algorithms. Bubble Sort is working fine, but Selection Sort don't care about how much time I put in the setInterval timer, he runs on the same speed no matter what (until I manually put sleep, but that's not the solution)

Can you guys help me understand what's wrong here? It's strange, because bubble sort works very good.

Bubble Sort

```
function bubbleSort(X, Y, LastX, LastY, no_loops, no_steps, time) {
  var i, j;
  var len = LastY.length;
  var isSwapped = false;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
      isSwapped = false;
      for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (LastY[j] > LastY[j + 1]) {
          var temp = LastY[j]
          LastY[j] = LastY[j + 1];
          no_steps = no_steps + 1;
          LastY[j + 1] = temp;
          no_steps = no_steps + 1;
          isSwapped = true;
        }
      }

      drawArray(X, Y, LastX, LastY);
      no_loops = no_loops + 1;
      no_steps = no_steps + 1;
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = no_loops;
      document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = no_steps;
      if (isArraySorted(LastY) == true) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, time);
    if (!isSwapped) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Selection Sort

```
function selectionSort(X, Y, LastX, LastY, no_loops, no_steps, time) {
  let n = LastY.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

          let min = i;
          for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (LastY[j] < LastY[min]) {
              min = j;
            }
            no_steps = no_steps + 1;
          }
          if (min != i)
            let tmp = LastY[i];
          LastY[i] = LastY[min];
          LastY[min] = tmp;
          no_steps = no_steps + 1;
        }
        drawArray(X, Y, LastX, LastY);
        //sleep(time);
        console.log(time) no_loops = no_loops + 1; no_steps = no_steps + 1;
        if (isArraySorted(LastY) == true) {
          return;
        }
        console.log(i); document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = no_loops; document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = no_steps;

        if (isArraySorted(LastY) == true) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
      },
      time);
}

}
```

I was trying parsing code block in interval to external function, changing placement of setInterval, but i can't get it to draw properly.

Comment: You should include enough code to make this executable. You did not provide the `isArraySorted` and `drawArray` functions, nor did you show how the sorting methods are called.

Comment: You're starting multiple interval timers in the loop, but overwriting the `intervalId` variable each time. So `clearInterval(intervalId)` will only stop the last one, the others will keep running.

Comment: Remember that variables declared with `var` are scoped to the function, not the block.

Comment: The brackets don't match properly in the selection sort code. This should get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach, you will have an increasing number of issues with the more complex sorting algorithms.

Why not just use [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) to return control to your main function to draw the current state on every step of sorting?

```js
const isArraySorted = arr => arr.every((v,i,a) => !i || a[i-1] <= v);

function *bubbleSort(X, Y, LastX, LastY, no_loops, no_steps) {
  var i, j;
  var len = LastY.length;
  var isSwapped = false;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    isSwapped = false;
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      if (LastY[j] > LastY[j + 1]) {
        var temp = LastY[j]
        LastY[j] = LastY[j + 1];
        no_steps = no_steps + 1;
        LastY[j + 1] = temp;
        no_steps = no_steps + 1;
        isSwapped = true;
      }
    }
    no_loops = no_loops + 1;
    no_steps = no_steps + 1;

    yield {
      X,
      Y,
      LastX,
      LastY,
      no_loops,
      no_steps
    };

    if (isArraySorted(LastY) == true) {
      return;
    }

    if (!isSwapped) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

const LastX = [4, 3, 2, 1];
const LastY = [4, 3, 2, 1];

const iterator = bubbleSort(0, 0, LastX, LastY, 0, 0);
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  const state = iterator.next().value;
  if (!state) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
  }
  // draw the current state provided by yield
  console.log(state.LastY);
}, 1000);
```

And with the Selection sort

```js
const isArraySorted = arr => arr.every((v, i, a) => !i || a[i - 1] <= v);

function *selectionSort(X, Y, LastX, LastY, no_loops, no_steps) {
  let n = LastY.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let min = i;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (LastY[j] < LastY[min]) {
        min = j;
      }
      no_steps = no_steps + 1;
    }
    if (min != i) {
      let tmp = LastY[i];
      LastY[i] = LastY[min];
      LastY[min] = tmp;
    }
    no_steps = no_steps + 1;
    
    yield {
      X,
      Y,
      LastX,
      LastY,
      no_loops,
      no_steps
    };

    if (isArraySorted(LastY)) {
      return;
    }
  }  
}

const LastX = [4, 3, 2, 1];
const LastY = [4, 3, 2, 1];

const iterator = selectionSort(0, 0, LastX, LastY, 0, 0);
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  const state = iterator.next().value;
  if (!state) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
  }
  // draw the current state provided by yield
  console.log(state.LastY);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hey @PatrykSmoliśki, don't you mind picking this answer as a solution if it is helpful for you? Thanks!

Comment: I cliked green checkbox, first time doing this. Is it accepted as solution now?

Comment: Also https://patryk0802.pythonanywhere.com/algo/

Job is done, many thanks to you one more time;) Not the best code in the world, but it works ;)

Comment: @PatrykSmoliśki whoa! Looks cool! So many algos! Great job! 

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i did not gave you enough info.
@RAllen, you are a genious, thank you. It's working like a charm now. I need just google what "*" means before function.

@Mr. Polywhirl
@Barmar

Full code below

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['time'])) {
    $time = $_POST['time'];
} else {
    $time = 50;
}
if (isset($_POST['elements'])) {
    $elements = $_POST['elements'];
} else {
    $elements = 1000;
}
if (isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
    $worstcase = 1;
    $checked = 'checked=""';
} else {
    $worstcase = 0;
    $checked = '';
}
if (isset($_POST['SortButton'])) {
    $alg_type = $_POST['SortButton'];
} else {
    $alg_type = 'bubble';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sorting algorithms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/canvas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/button.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/checkbox.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <th style="width:10%"></th>
        <th style="width:80%"><center><canvas id="canvasElement" class="inline-block-centered" width="1300" height="800"></canvas></center></th>
        <th style="width:10%" valign="top" align="left">Number of loops through array:<p id="p1">0</p>Number of all steps:<p id="p2">0</p></th>
    </table>
    <div class="slidecontainer"><br>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <label for="elements">
                <input type="range" id="elements" name="elements" value="<?php echo $elements;?>" min="5" max="10000" class="slider" oninput="elementsOutput.value = elements.value"><br>
                Number of elements to sort (range: 5-10000):<output id="elementsOutput"><?php echo $elements;?></output><br><br>
            </label>
            <label for="time">
                <input type="range" id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo $time;?>" min="1" max="1000" class="slider" oninput="timeOutput.value = time.value"><br>
                Time in miliseconds between each sort (range: 1-1000):<output id="timeOutput"><?php echo $time;?></output><br>
            </label>
            <label for="checkbox1" class="checkbox">
            <br><br>
                <span class="label">REVERSE ARRAY</span>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" <?php echo $checked;?>>
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label><br>
        <button type="submit" id="SortButton" name="SortButton" value="bubble" class="button-36">Bubble<br>SORT!</button>
        <button type="submit" id="SortButton" name="SortButton" value="selection" class="button-36">Selection<br>SORT!</button>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
//Declare Variables
var c = document.getElementById('canvasElement');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasElement');
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.7;
function windowResize() {
  canvas.width  = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.7;
};

window.addEventListener('resize', windowResize);

var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var X = [];
var LastX = [];
var Y = [];
var LastY = [];

ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "start";
ctx.fillText("textAlign=start", canvas.width, canvas.height);

var number = <?php echo $elements;?>;
var time = <?php echo $time;?>;
var worstcase = <?php echo $worstcase;?>;
console.log(number);
var pos_x = canvas.width - (canvas.width/number/2);
var pos_y = canvas.height;
var delay = canvas.width/number;
var delay_y = canvas.height/number
</script>

<script type="module">
import { drawArray } from './js/drawArray.js';
import { createArray } from './js/createArray.js';
import { shuffle } from './js/shuffleArray.js';
import * as sorting from './js/sortingAlgorithms.js';

createArray(X, Y, LastX, LastY, number, window.innerHeight);
if (worstcase == 0){
    LastY = shuffle(LastY);
}
drawArray(X, Y, LastX, LastY);

var no_loops = 1;
var no_steps = 1;

const iterator = sorting.<?php echo $alg_type;?>Sort(X, Y, LastX, LastY, no_loops, no_steps, time);
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  const state = iterator.next().value;
  if (!state) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  drawArray(X, Y, LastX, LastY);
}, time);
</script>


</body>
</html>

        


    import { drawArray } from './drawArray.js';
import { isArraySorted } from './isArraySorted.js';

export function *bubbleSort(X, Y, LastX, LastY, no_loops, no_steps) {
  var i, j;
  var len = LastY.length;
  var isSwapped = false;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    isSwapped = false;
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      if (LastY[j] > LastY[j + 1]) {
        var temp = LastY[j]
        LastY[j] = LastY[j + 1];
        no_steps = no_steps + 1;
        LastY[j + 1] = temp;
        no_steps = no_steps + 1;
        isSwapped = true;
      }
    }
    no_loops = no_loops + 1;
    no_steps = no_steps + 1;

    yield {
      X,
      Y,
      LastX,
      LastY,
      no_loops,
      no_steps
    };

    if (isArraySorted(LastY) == true) {
      return;
    }

    if (!isSwapped) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

export function *selectionSort(X, Y, LastX, LastY, no_loops, no_steps) {
  let n = LastY.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let min = i;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (LastY[j] < LastY[min]) {
        min = j;
      }
      no_steps = no_steps + 1;
    }
    if (min != i) {
      let tmp = LastY[i];
      LastY[i] = LastY[min];
      LastY[min] = tmp;
    }
    no_steps = no_steps + 1;
    
    yield {
      X,
      Y,
      LastX,
      LastY,
      no_loops,
      no_steps
    };

    if (isArraySorted(LastY)) {
      return;
    }
  }  
}

    
export function createArray(X, Y, LastX, LastY, number, height) {
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        X.push(pos_x);
        LastX.push(pos_x);
        Y.push(height);
        LastY.push(pos_y);
        pos_x = pos_x - delay;
        pos_y = pos_y - delay_y;
        
    }
}

    export function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }
  return array;
}

    export function isArraySorted(arr) {
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if (arr[i+1] && (arr[i+1] > arr[i])) {
            continue;
        } else if(arr[i+1] && (arr[i+1] < arr[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

    export function drawArray(X, Y, LastX, LastY) {
    for (var i = 0; i < X.length; ++i) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(LastX[i],LastY[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(X[i],Y[i]);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries! Happy to help! `*` means that the function is a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), and this allows you to use `yield` operator. Don't you mind picking my answer as a "Solution" if it is useful? Thanks!